# POST raw json code ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode

i'm new to ios developing and i want to ask how can i post a raw json code to the server.

For Example: i want to send this JSON raw data to http://example.com/user

```
{ 
  "user": 
    {   
        "username": "jkaaannyaad11",
        "password": "secret123456",
        "gender": "male",
        "first_name": "assd",
        "last_name": "ffsasd",
        "birth_date": "can be null",
        "phone_number": "12343234",
        "have_car":"1",
        "same_gender" :"0",
        "uid": "this is id for facebook , can be null"
    },
  "home":
    {
        "longitude": "31.380301",
        "latitude": "30.054272",
        "name": "city"
    },
  "work":
    {
        "longitude": "30.068237",
        "latitude": "31.024275",
        "name": "village"
    },
  "email": 
    {
        "email_type": "work",
        "email": "hello.me@me.com"
    }
}
```

so how can i do it ?

For Example in Android using the JSONObject i can easily oraganize them and then POST them to the website

```
   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject userObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject homeObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject workObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject emailObj = new JSONObject();

        try {
            obj.put("user", userObj);
            obj.put("home", homeObj);
            obj.put("work", workObj);
            obj.put("email", emailObj);

homeObj.put("longitude", homePlace.LocationRef.Lng);
            homeObj.put("latitude", homePlace.LocationRef.Lat);
            homeObj.put("name", homePlace.LocationRef.Address);
```

Comment: Can you show examples of code you've already tried?

Comment: @TopherHunt i'm sorry i didn't try any ... Acctually, i've been trying with android 
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject userObj = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject homeObj = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject workObj = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject emailObj = new JSONObject();

  try {
   obj.put("user", userObj);
   obj.put("home", homeObj);
   obj.put("work", workObj);
   obj.put("email", emailObj);

homeObj.put("longitude", homePlace.LocationRef.Lng);
   homeObj.put("latitude", homePlace.LocationRef.Lat);
   homeObj.put("name", homePlace.LocationRef.Address);

Answer (score 3):

Use the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library. On the repository page there are many examples including the one below to make a `POST` request.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but what about if the database has a username and a password to connect to ? how can i add them as a header ?